# How can I specify cross-correlations between differential equations?

Tags: correlation, stochastic-processes, cross-correlation, differential-equations

For my Master thesis I want to model co-movements between two commodity forward curve. First, I specify the model for a single forward curve

$F(t,T)= \bar{F}_0(t)e^{s(T_i)-y(t,T-t)(T-t)}$

where $F(t,T)$ is the forward curve at time $t$ for maturity $T$, $\bar{F}_0(t)$ is the forward curve level (is my first factor), $s(T_i)$ is the seasonal premium per month for $i^{th}$ year of maturity (is deterministic), $y(t,T-t)$ is the convenience yield (second factor).

Now I want to simulate and describe the dynamics of the two factors,

$d(\log \bar{F}_{0,j}(t))=dX_i(t)=k_i (\mu -X_i (t))dt+ \sigma dW_i^1 (t) \mbox{ with   }      d W_i^1dW_j^1=\rho^1_{i,j}dt$

where $dW_i^1$ is a wiener process for commodity i and $dW_j^1$ for commodity j, The first factor of commodity i should be correlated to the first factor of commodity j.

The dynamics of the second factor are,

$dy_i(t, T-t)= -a^{T-t} y(t,T-t)dt + \eta _i dW_i^2(t) \mbox{ with   } dW_i^2dW_j^2=\rho^2_{i,j}dt$

again, from my historical dataset the convenience yield of both commodities should be correlated with each other.. Therefore, $dW_i^2dW_1^2=\rho^2_{i,j}dt$.

So far, I do not think I made any mistakes, but now I want to specify the correlation relationship for the same commodity but between the two factors? How can I specify the correlation relationship for one commodity, i, but for different factors?

I thought may be something like:

$dW_i^1dW_i^2=\rho^{1,2}_{i}dt$

Comment: My suggestion is correct.. I asked a mathematician